# Crosscompiling GCC: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES when checking dynamic linker characteristics

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile `gcc-4.8.3` for LFS by following [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html).

When using `make`, I get the following error:

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Configure options:

```
../configure                                       \
    --target=$LFS_TGT                              \
    --prefix=/tools                                \
    --with-glibc-version=2.11                      \
    --with-sysroot=$LFS                            \
    --with-newlib                                  \
    --without-headers                              \
    --with-local-prefix=/tools                     \
    --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include \
    --disable-nls                                  \
    --disable-shared                               \
    --disable-multilib                             \
    --disable-decimal-float                        \
    --disable-threads                              \
    --disable-libatomic                            \
    --disable-libgomp                              \
    --disable-libmpx                               \
    --disable-libquadmath                          \
    --disable-libssp                               \
    --disable-libvtv                               \
    --disable-libstdcxx                            \
    --enable-languages=c,c++
```

where `$LFS_TGT` is `x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu`.

`config.log` on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/JVfmrAzj).

Last few lines of output:

```
checking if /mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for /mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if /mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if /mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    static flag -static works... no
checking if /mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if /mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the /mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    linker (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build/./gcc/collect-ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/Projects/AssaultArchitecture/sources/gcc-4.8.3/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: This could be just a plain old bug in GCC's build scripts.  Try using a newer release.  4.8.x is quite old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building LFS, You should check the user which you are using and make sure it's not root.

Comment: I was building LFS on WSL, which only provides a root user. The issue was solved on building natively on linux  using a non-root user. Note, the original post is from 2017.

Comment: I ran into this issue on linux as well, accidentally compiling as root instead of the lfs user as I thought. Starting over as a non-root user solved the problem. This answer would benefit from some explanation. How did you know this was the issue?

Answer (score 9):

If you're building this on a `x86_64` machine and you have `x86_64` as target, you're not actually building a cross compiler.
You seem to be building an *isolated stage1 compiler*, so you have to add `--disable-bootstrap` flag. GCC by default disables bootstrap if your build target platform is not the native platform (a cross compiler).

Comment: What if you're on x86_64 (ELF) and you're targeting i386 with a different binary format (a.out)?

Comment: Makes sense and that was what my issue was.  At the time of this post I was attempting to build LFS native with the systemd variant, which seems to pull in content from the cross-compiling documentation.  I was leaving out the target flags, since it was native, but I didn't even think about disabling bootstrap.  I actually thought bootstrap was disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Exact same issue is covered here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-07/msg00018.html

It is suggested that an appropriate `glibc` may be missing (targeting `x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu`), and needs to be installed.

HTH.

Comment: I know that. I'm building a toolchain from scratch and this is the Pass1 compiler which will be used to build `glibc`. If you see the configure options, it is evident that `gcc` is to be compiled so that it rejects code containing `glibc` as a necessity.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I had visited that link prior to asking my question.

Comment: `--with-newlib`: 
Since a working C library is not yet available, this ensures that the `inhibit_libc` constant is defined when building `libgcc`. This prevents the compiling of any code that requires `libc` support.

Comment: `--without-headers` tells GCC not to rely on any C library (standard or runtime) being present for the target.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Could you upload the make build output to pastebin as well? If so, I'd be happy to give another eye. It may help to understand where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inspect `config.log` to find out which command `configure` tried to run; for example:

```
configure:9604: checking whether the x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc linker (/usr/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
) supports shared libraries
configure:10684: result: no
configure:10929: checking dynamic linker characteristics
configure:11375: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
```

In this case, run `/usr/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64` manually. It might yield something like:

```
/usr/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So in this case you would know that `libz.so.1` cannot be found.

Comment: This is the frequent general pattern of `Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES` problems. A tool built in an earlier stage of the GCC build (such as `ld` here, `xgcc`, `collect2`, etc.) is failing to even launch, probably because of a problem finding a shared lib, and in the later configure it causes a check to detect an impossible situation where more checks with link tests would be necessary. To solve it you check the `config.log`s and find the tool and its error, fix whatever underlying issue led to it not launching, and restart the GCC build from the beginning