# Troubles in build GCC continuing

Tags: linux, compiler-errors

So i tried to build the gcc in lfs needed to build glibc refering to the chapter 5.3 and got this error

```
make[2]: *** [Makefile:13792: configure-stage2-zlib] Error 1
yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for CET support... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:12061: configure-stage2-libiberty] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21586: stage2-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1027: all] Error 2
```

how i can resolve this error and normally build gcc
configure command(taken from lfs book):

```
    --target=$LFS_TGT         \
    --prefix=$LFS/tools       \
    --with-glibc-version=2.38 \
    --with-sysroot=$LFS       \
    --with-newlib             \
    --without-headers         \
    --enable-default-pie      \
    --enable-default-ssp      \
    --disable-nls             \
    --disable-shared          \
    --disable-multilib        \
    --disable-threads         \
    --disable-libatomic       \
    --disable-libgomp         \
    --disable-libquadmath     \
    --disable-libssp          \
    --disable-libvtv          \
    --disable-libstdcxx       \
    --enable-languages=c,c++
```

I tried all methods described in all resources, but no one is worked...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crosscompiling GCC: Link tests are not allowed after GCC\_NO\_EXECUTABLES when checking dynamic linker characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487529/crosscompiling-gcc-link-tests-are-not-allowed-after-gcc-no-executables-when-che)

Comment: Looks like LFS-12.0 . ... When asking LFS questions, the LFS version and the OS version must be specified. And the result from `version-check.sh` must be OK   https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/stable-systemd/LFS-BOOK-12.0-NOCHUNKS.html#version-check  ..... Some OS may still cause issues . (Slackware is said to be OK.)

Comment: thanks. I will know if i decide to install LFS next time what i need to do if error occurs